# PHP undefined variable error how to define

Tags: php, variables

I am creating a user "friend system" from a tutorial on Youtube. Everything is working fine except the "members" page. I want it to display all the site's members by their username. I have been over this part of the tutorial several times, and am pretty sure that i have not made an error. But, when I test the page out, it lists all the members, but does not display the username. I get this error

**"Notice: Undefined index: $field in J:\TestSite\socialnetworkcode\functions.php on line 16"**

I know that the variable "$field" is undefined in the functions page, the strange part is that his (the person who created the tutorial) page works fine and diplays the usernames. I do not know what to define it as, or why his works without defining "$field" and mine doesn't.

```
<?php

session_start();

function loggedin(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){
   return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
}

function getuser($id, $field){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT $field FROM users WHERE id='$id'");
    $run = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    return $run['$field'];

}

?>
```

Comment: danron, look closer.  He's trying to return the dynamic variable $field, not the string $field.  Your solution wouldn't work!

Answer (score 1):

You're telling it to return the string $field, when you really want to have it return the variable $field.

Change your last line to return `$run[$field]`